# operator-sdk does not accept cluster-scoped keyword

Tags: openshift, kubernetes-operator, operator-sdk

I am using operator-sdk version v0.11.0. But when I try to create  new project using --cluster-scope option it does not recognize that option and fails with unknown option `cluster-scope`. I am new to operators. Any idea what am I missing.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `--cluster-scope` option is removed now, refer [here](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/pull/1434) for more details. But don't worry you can adjust cluster scope through this configuration, [Operator SDK: Operator Scope](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/blob/master/doc/operator-scope.md)
. I hope it help you. Thanks.